# Module 'AudioKit' has no member named 'output' How to check the version of AudioKit actually got installed

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

```
pod 'AudioKit', '4.11.2'
pod 'Charts', '3.6.0'
```

My podfile includes two pods: AudioKit and Charts.

I am currently using AudioKit version 4.11.2 and got this error

```
Module 'AudioKit' has no member named 'output'
```

[Xcode Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXOea.png)

So I wonder, how can I find the actual version of AudioKit that has been installed on my machine. I do not want to upgrade to AudioKit version 5 since the whole codebase is based on version 4. I am planning to change the entire code after I can run the app first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `AKManager.output` instead of `AudioKit.output`